# How can I remove a deleted chatroom from the favorite rooms?

Tags: bug, chat, deleted-room

Several of chatrooms I have favorited have been [deleted or frozen for inactivity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention). They still remain among my favorite rooms (which is good; but I think I should have a possibility to remove them if I decide to do so).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In this screenshot the room called *Testing feeds* have been frozen and it still has a star which, when I hover above it, shows a tooltip *Toggle as a favorite room*. But there are also two rooms that have been deleted, where this star is not shown. And I have not found any other way how to remove them from my favorites. (The fourth room in this screenshot is still alive.)

Is there a way how to remove a deleted chatroom from your favorites?

---

P.S. 
I was not sure whether to tag this post as [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug); but I thought that my first assumption should be that I simply didn't find way to do this rather than assume that the software does not allow this.

Comment: @Gilles I stumbled upon a closely related question - maybe even a duplicate: [How do I 'unfavorite' a deleted room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224576) (Since you put "Authoritative reference needed" bounty here, I thought it might be of interest to you. Although the answer says basically the same thing.

Comment: The duplicate question was marked as a bug, and that seems to have been uncontroversial because it lived as a bug for three years. There is a workaround, so it's a low priority bug, to be sure. I have now proposed a tag edit to add the bug tag here also.

Comment: Another related post: [Unable to unstar frozen or deleted chat rooms from SE chat rooms lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280496).

Comment: How utterly bizarre: The star icon is available on deleted rooms if you're a moderator (at least the ones where you have moderator privileges). There's no good reason for this restriction, especially since there's a workaround.

Answer (score 13):

Now I have noticed that after joining the room, the star - which enables to toggle whether room is favorite - becomes available. (I did not try this before, since I simply did not try to join a room which is already deleted.)

I still think that it would be nice to be able to do this from the list of favorited rooms (in the same way as for frozen and active rooms), but I do not think that this problem occurs very often; so it is not that important.

[image]