# How do I 'unfavorite' a deleted room?

Tags: bug, chat, bookmarks

On the favorites tab of the [chat.stackexchange.com page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=favorite&sort=active), there is a 'rejoin all' button that I use frequently. There are a number of rooms I once favorited that have since been deleted and 'rejoin all' puts me in those too.

[image]

I'd like to 'unfavorite' those deleted rooms, but I can't work out how (short of undeleting them first). The star I'd usually click on is absent:

[image]
[image]

Is there some easy way to do this I'm missing or should I re-tag this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

Comment: Is it also missing from the top right panel once you enter the room?

Comment: No it's not missing from there, that's helpful thanks. It is missing from the 'info' page for the room though.

Comment: Yes, I agree it should be available in all the places where it was before the deletion (i.e. that sounds like a bug to me).  I don't have a convenient test case, which is why I asked instead of just going to look.

Comment: Related question: [How to remove deleted chatroom from favorite rooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196853)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Because this question was recently closed as a dupe, and the primary question, unlike this one, lacks the [tag:bug] tag, I've edited the primary question to propose adding the [tag:bug] tag.

Comment: Another related post: [Unable to unstar frozen or deleted chat rooms from SE chat rooms lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280496)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The star is missing from the "rooms" list (from which the screen shot was taken) and the "info" page for the individual room.  However, if you enter the room it's still present there, so you can enter, unstar, leave, and never have to be automatically signed into the room again.

(This information gathered from debugging in comments.)

Comment: Well, this is a bit of a kludge... Pity there's no other way.