# Unable to unstar frozen or deleted chat rooms from SE chat rooms lists

Tags: bug, chat, frozen-rooms, deleted-room, favorite-rooms

I have found that when a chat room becomes "frozen" or "deleted", then if I have starred it I am forced to enter the actual room in order to unstar it as the unstarring option is removed from the SE chat room lists as you can see here:

[image: No unstar option in SE chat room list]

I assume that this is to prevent people from starring frozen or deleted chat rooms? But the unstar option should not be removed - only the star option if the room is not already starred.

As it becomes rather annoying to have to click at least 3 buttons to unstar a room (and the room may take a while to load depending on how much content it has, so this whole process could take a while) it would be nice just to have the nice and easy option like with the other chat rooms.  Especially if you have more than 1 or 2 rooms you would like to unstar.

Comment: As a workaround, you can run this from your browser's console while in a page under the chat domain: `$.post("/rooms/favorite", {roomId: [room number here], fkey: $("#fkey").val()});` e.g. `$.post("/rooms/favorite", {roomId: 89, fkey: $("#fkey").val()});` to favorite/unfavorite the Tavern here in MSE chat. This works both for active and frozen rooms.

Comment: This seems like more of a feature request than a bug. Further, this is a corner case of corner cases... how many times have you ever dealt with unstarring a room? How many times have you done that with a frozen room? (For me, the answer to both is zero)

Comment: @hichris123 Disagree: I have five chat rooms (surely to increase) that were deleted due to inactivity, that had all been favourited, and that are now stuck in my favourites. This is not edgy.

Answer (score 2):

@ShadowWizardHatesOmicron's workaround succeeds, with an asterisk: when writing something like

```js
$.post("/rooms/favorite", {roomId: [
    127945, 111055, 98513, 107159, 98897
], fkey: $("#fkey").val()});
```

only the first ID will be respected; so it seems it's only ever useful to pass a list of one ID.

Comment: Another possible workaround is to join the room and unstar from there: [How to remove deleted chatroom from favorite rooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196853#196962) and [How do I 'unfavorite' a deleted room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224576#224586)

Comment: @Martin That one can Join the room to unstar it is mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that - I should have read the post more carefully. (In any case, at least the comments adds the post to the linked questions.) Thanks for noticing my mistake, @TheAmplitwist.